# jquery - pass json from one html file to another

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am a novice web designer. I have just started using jQuery. I have a first web page and based on the user inputs, i create a json. I need to pass this json to the second page and show the contents of json using the elements of the second page. I use jquery's .load method to pass the values to the second page.

```
$('.contentsDiv').load('second.html', createdjson)
```

What is the correct way for passing json between web pages? Should i do any kind of formatting in my json before sending? How far ajax call is different from this?

How do i access this json in my second page?

I tried searching SO but couldn't get the answer...
Please give your valuable suggestions...

Comment: I dont think jSON/Ajax can do what you looking for. By using `.load`, you are basically pulling the content of `second.html` into the `.contentsDiv`. However, you could use the same idea, but on the second page, but you will not be able to pull a specific div.

Comment: How do i get the json in my second page @AKKA ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to save the data before navigating over. Normally, one uses some sort of server-side language if data persistence is needed, but this would provide a client-side only way of doing so.